# How to detect when user presses close button

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

How would you know when the user pressed the "x" button on the close button in a python kivy program and do an event?

Comment: To the close voters: this question is simple, clear, and on-topic. Why should it be closed? What's too broad about it?